# What are the default JSLint options?

Tags: jslint

There are many [JSLint options](http://www.jslint.com/#JSLINT_OPTIONS) with which to configure the extent by which JSLint may ignore code quality issues.

The web interface, for boolean options, allows you to toggle between choices of `true`, `false` and `default`. This implies that if a given option has no explicit value chosen a default, or implicit, value will be used.

Many options allow for certain "bad" uses of JavaScript to be tolerated, implying that the default is 'false'. as one intent of JSLint is to discourage "bad" uses.

If merely `true` or `false` were possible choices, with `false` being the default, a regular checkbox, or any other input offering binary and not ternary choices, might be expected to be used. Given that the web interface allows for one's choice to revert to `default` suggests that `false` might not always be the default choice for a given option.

It is not clear to me from examining the [latest source](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/blob/master/jslint.js) what values the selection of options will take if not explicitly chosen.

For all the JSLint options, what default values are used?

Am I correct in assuming that boolean options default to 'false' if not specified and that integer options (indent, maxerr and maxlen) default to those values [present in the source](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/blob/master/jslint.js#L352-L354)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JSLint, all of the boolean options are `false` by default. That effectively means that JSLint is as strict as it can be. All of the options, when set, will lessen the restrictions it places on your code.

I think the reason the web interface uses those "true"/"false"/"default" toggles is that there is a different behaviour for the `global` directive. The default state for any global identifier is simply "not present" - click one of them to add a set of global identifiers as `true`, click again to set them to `false`, and click again to remove that set of identifiers.

If global identifiers are listed with `true`, then JSLint will not complain if it encounters an assignment. If `false`, an assignment to a global identifier will generate a warning. Again, `false` is the default:

```
/*global $ */           // Define $ globally, don't allow assignments
/*global $:false */     // Equivalent to the above
/*global $:true */      // Allow assignment
```